# Erlang gen_tcp closes port that gets wrong by GCDAsynchSocket

Tags: ios, objective-c, tcp, erlang, gcdasyncsocket

I stuck with a problem. I have an iOS client and a tcp server on Erlang/OTP. The client suppose to send and receive messages to the server through GCDAsynchSocket. It works pretty well if I need to send a message but It doesn't as acceptor, because the client has to call this delegate method:

`/**
 * Called when a socket has completed reading the requested data into memory.
 * Not called if there is an error.
**/
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag;`

the problem is that server closes the connection, that invokes another delegate method(
`- (void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err;`
).
How to complete reading data from the server in the client and how to leave working connections on the server until a client will be disconnected by itself? iOS client gets bytes from the server but cannot close connection as normal.

part of the Erlang server:

```
-behaviour (gen_server).

-export ([start_link/0, check_data/1]).

%%gen_server callbacks
-export ([init/1, handle_call/3,
        handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
        terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-define (PORT, 1477).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [?PORT], []).


init([Port]) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, 
        [{active, false},
         binary,
         {reuseaddr, true}]), 
    spawn(fun() ->
    accept_parallel(Listen) end),
    io:format("~p started~n", [?MODULE]),
    {ok, 0}.

accept_parallel(Listen) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
    spawn(fun() -> accept_parallel(Listen)  end),
    loop(Socket).

handle_call(Request, _From, N) ->
    {reply, Request, N + 1}.

handle_cast(_Msg, N) -> 
    {noreply, N}.

handle_info(_Info, N) -> 
    {noreply, N}.   

terminate(_Reason, _N) ->
    io:format("~p stoped~n", [?MODULE]),
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, N, _Extra) -> {ok, N}.

loop(Socket) ->
    case gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) of
        {ok, Bin} ->
            case check_data(Bin) of
            ok ->
                gen_tcp:send(Socket, "ok");
            {error, _Data} ->
                gen_tcp:send(Socket, "error")       
            end;
        {error, Reason} ->
            exit(Reason)
    end.
```

I can put a timeout after sending a message to the client but anyway how can I finish accepting data up?

Update: I need to connect just once for proving authorization with sending a token back to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I hope it will help to someone. 
A little correction on the server:

```
loop(Socket) ->
    inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),         
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Bin} ->
            Answer = check_data(Bin),
            gen_tcp:send(Socket, atom_to_binary(Answer, utf8)),
            loop(Socket);
        {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            io:format("Socket ~p closed [~p]~n", [Socket, self()]),
            ok  
    end.    

check_data(Bin) ->
    Data = mochijson:decode(Bin),
    case Data of
                {struct, [{"login", Name}, {"password", Password}]} = NewUser ->
                    io:format("We got a new user:~n  Name - ~p~n  Password - ~p~n", [Name, Password]),
                    spawn(fun() -> save_data(NewUser) end),
                    ok;
                Any ->
                    io:format("We got ~p~n", [Any]),
                    error   
            end.
```

and the client:

```
#pragma mark - managing TCP connection

- (IBAction)signInPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *login = [_loginTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *password = [_passwordTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    NSDictionary *loginInformation = @{@"login" : login, @"password" : password};

    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:loginInformation
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:nil];
    //[socket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0]; if you need to get more than one response
    [socket writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
}

- (void)initTCPConnection
{
    NSError *err;

    if (![socket connectToHost:@"192.168.1.7" onPort:1477 error:&err]) {
        NSLog(@"We got an error - %@", err);
    }

    NSLog(@"We are fine");
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sender didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    NSLog(@"connected!");
    [socket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag
{
    NSLog(@"First request sent");
}

-(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {

    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"MSG: %@",msg);
}
```

In my case, I couldn't get in didReadData with other methods such as readDataToData: etc. Good Luck.

Comment: Wow. That turned out to be way easier to read this time. Good job.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. @zxq9

Answer (score 2):

Your loop isn't looping, so once your case expression is evaluated your process is exiting (nothing left to do) and gen_tcp closes the connection for you on process exit. You need to add `loop(Socket)` at the end of loop/1:

```
loop(Socket) ->
    case gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) of
        % stuff...
    end,
    loop(Socket).
```

Personally, though, I prefer following the more general `receive` style with gen_tcp than `gen_tcp:recv/2` as illustrated in this example:

```
loop(S) ->
    inet:setopts(S,[{active,once}]),
    receive
        {tcp,S,Data} ->
            Answer = process(Data), % business logic here
            gen_tcp:send(S,Answer),
            loop(S);
        {tcp_closed,S} ->
            io:format("Socket ~w closed [~w]~n",[S,self()]),
            ok
    end.
```

The above example was pulled from the [gen_tcp](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html) docs, and is rather similar to the way you'll see folks implement a hybrid socket style. For me, at least, this method clears up my reasoning at the same time it prevents data floods.

Comment: Probably, I supposed to say that I need to connect just once for proving authorization with sending a token back to the client. Anyway Thanks a lot

Comment: @AndreyNechaev Connecting "just once" in TCP (especially for authorization) is almost never actually receive/send just once as far as the mechanics of the auth protocol are concerned (but it could be). Also, note that simply adding `loop(Socket)` as I did above means your code loops until it crashes -- you need to call exit somewhere in there. Anyway, the main reason I use the more general `receive` instead of `gen_tcp:recv` is because it prevents me from writing nested conditionals -- something I *really* hate doing in functional languages.

Comment: Your answer is good as style recommendation, I had almost the same loop method and now I got back to it. Thank you for your advice. I assume, my question was more about gcdasynchsocket. Anyway, that's my flat that I couldn't write it clear. Sorry